# How to insert non-parceable and non-serializable object into Bundle

Tags: android, twitter, bundle, serializable

I'm using the twitter API for android.
From a call, a List of 'Tweet' objects is returned. I want to save this list into my savedInstanceBundle when required so I don't have to make the large http call again. The problem is that 'Tweet' does not implement parceable or serializable so I cant input it into the bundle.

What are my options?

```
Call<List<Tweet>> lookup = apiclient.getStatusesService().lookup(ids, true, false, false);

lookup.enqueue(new Callback<List<Tweet>>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<List<Tweet>> result) {
            Response response = result.response;
            List<Tweet> tweets = result.data; //what I'd like to save
        }
```

Comment: Post of your code of getting Tweet objects?how do you hold those objects without having Tweet class?

Comment: The API returns a List of 'Call' items given a bunch of twitter post IDs. You can then make an http request for each 'Call'. The result of the call, given in a callback, is a List of 'Tweet' objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  All you can do is take the information from it, create your own object that is Parcelable or Serializable, and send that.

Answer (score 2):

You can not do this its mentioned in doc also . Object should be Marshal before passing for that you can use `Serializable` or `parcelable`.

The other way you can use an data-interchange format like `JSON` or `XML` or any other . But this way it will much more to write for marshal and unmarshal. So you better make use of `Bundle.putParcelable/Bundle.getParcelable` or `Bundle.putSerializable/Bundle.getSerializable` .

It also depends on where exactly you passing  the Object . You should look at [Be Careful Where You Use Custom Parcelables](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/07/22/be-careful-where-you-use-custom-parcelables.html) . One of the Scholar Commansware's blog.

If you need to  pass object beetween component when application in foreground then `Parcelables` is the  best way .

Comment: could elaborate further on "Marshal"?